# Callback js Google is empty

Tags: javascript, maps

Im have js function, she calc latitude and longitude from zip code:

```js
function GetLocation(adr, callback) {
        var address = adr;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function (results, status) {

          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
              var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
              // console.log([latitude, longitude])
               callback([latitude, longitude]);
          } else {
              return "Request failed.";
          }
        });
      }
```

When I call function in origin:

```js
if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {

              var myRouter = {
                  map_: null,
                  directionsHelper_: null,

                  calcRoute: function() {

                      var waypts = [];

                      for (var i in this.stores) {
                          waypts.push({
                              location: this.stores[i].location,
                              stopover:true
                          });
                      }



                      var request = {

                          origin: new google.maps.LatLng(
                            GetLocation(adress1, function(callback) {
                              console.log(callback[0]);
                            }),
                            GetLocation(adress1, function(callback) {
                              console.log(callback[1]);
                            })
                          ),
```

Callback return is empty, if call before if(navigator.geolocation) that ok, how I can fix it?